# Подсчет количества каждого значения таблицы

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

Имеется `table_1` со столбцом `field_1`, содержащим не-уникальные значения, вида:

```
2
2
2
3
3
5
```

И т.д.
Необходимо найти count каждого значения этого столбца - результат должен иметь вид

```
2 3
2 3
2 3
3 2
3 2
5 1
```

Какую функцию правильнее применить к `field_1` для получения нужного результата?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В `Oracle` существуют аналитические функции, которые позволяют получить нужный результат.

```
select field_1, count(1) over(partition by field_1) from table_1
```