# Как вывести все записи с указанием количества повторений из PostgresQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Как сформировать запрос чтобы вывести все записи с указанием количества повторений Last_name, first_name из PostgresQL? Обязательно наличие ID
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: повторений чего ? именно имени ? `count(1) over(partition by first_name)`

Comment: спасибо большое, все получилось!

Comment: @Mike Оформите свой комментарий как ответ, или мне написать свой?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Подсчет количества каждого значения таблицы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/741309/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b)

Comment: @Ainar-G думаю надо по дублю закрыть

Comment: Там про Оракл, так что чёрт знает.